# Altera o "Web Reference URL" do Webservice adicionado por add web reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-service

Gostaria de saber se seria possível e como fazer está alteração pegando o endereço do web.config
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que alteração ?

Comment: @Pedro, adicionei uma imagem para ficar mais fácil o entendimeto

Comment: Não ficou claro. Do que você precisa especificamente ?

Comment: @Pedro, viu a imagem? quando você adicionar um webservice com a opção add web reference, ele já adiciona o caminho no Properties, eu quero pegar o caminho do web.config

Comment: Você precisa criar uma instância da classe do seu WebReference. Em seguida deve usar a propriedade Url.

Comment: @Pedro, quando tiver um tempo, poderia postar um exemplo prático como uma resposta nesta questão, agradeço

Comment: postei um exemplo. veja se é útil pro que precisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Web.config**

Dentro da tag  adicione a sua nova url para o Web Reference.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="urlWebService" value="http://www.google.com" />
</appSettings>
```

Quando você instanciar a classe proxy do seu Web Service, altere a URL para a url cadastrada no web.config:

```
using (var webService = new Foo.WebService())
{
    webService.Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["urlWebService"];
}
```

**Não se esqueça que os nomes que usei (site da google, Foo.WebService) são nomes fictícios, pois não sei o nome dos modelos do seu projeto.**

Comment: resposta perfeita, agradeço muito por ter dedicado um tempo na resposta.

Comment: Que nada, fico feliz por ter funcionado! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar uma instância da classe que deseja usar geradas pelas classes proxy do WebReference. Vou dar um exemplo utilizando o WebService dos correios.

Pode ser acessado usando o link abaixo:
http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx

Após adicionar a referencia do seu WebService, instancie e a classe e consulte a propriedade Url.

```
 br.com.correios.ws.CalcPrecoPrazoWS client = new br.com.correios.ws.CalcPrecoPrazoWS();

 string valorUrl = client.Url;
```